# Next js server side rendered page question

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I have main page with products, when I click on a product it's redirected to a product page /prducts/:productId which uses getServerSideProps to render it's data. When I go back to the main page with all products displayed I start again on the beginning of the page. To solve this problem I want instead of redirecting to /products/:productId I will use shallow routing just to change the URL and show the product page component in front of my main page, but I will keep /product/:productId page so if someone use the URL to access it he will go to this page which will be server side rendered.

So in conclusion I will display a component when user clicks on a product from main page and if user tries to access the page via URL I will redirect him to real page which is server side rendered. My question is will this hurt my search engine optimization or it has no impact on it ?

Answer (score 0):

For such situations you should take advantage of SSR & ISR (getStaticProps/getStaticPaths) as it boosts SEO by a lot.

And SSG's sole purpose is not to boost SEO but to decrease the page load time. I hope you may know about this.

Answer (score 0):

This will not hurt your SEO performance. There's nothing wrong with ensuring each product exists on its own URL (/products/productid). Showing the product component on the main page is just a usability improvement for users.

Here is Google's take on dynamic rendering:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/javascript/dynamic-rendering